# Which robust covariance estimator to use if I want to 1) robust against outlier 2) stay positive definite

Tags: scikit-learn, covariance, covariance-matrix, robust

I am now working on a very noisy dataset $X$ , which is a m-by-n matrix, with  m samples, each contains n  features

The n-by-n covariance matrix can be naively calculcated as $X^{T}X$

However, my data contains a lot of outliers. So I am tryingt to have a robust estimate of the covariance matrix. I tried the approach in sklearn"

[robust covariance estimation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_mahalanobis_distances.html)

however, I noticed that the resulting covariance matrix is NOT positive definite. I double checked the empirical covariance estimator, and the result is positive definite, as expected.

Can anyone explain to me why the covariance matrix is no longer positive definite ?

also, can anyone recommend an R/python package that can both handle outliers and stay positive definite?

Comment: You might try finding covariances on ranks of observations (instead of values). This mitigates the effect of outliers without having to delete them. This is in the spirit of using Spearman rather than Pearson correlation.